# Removing add "From SharePoint" feature in a forum

Tags: 2013, permissions

Whenever a user wants to start a topic in a SharePoint forum or respond to a topic, he can add an image or a link "from SharePoint".

When he clicks on "from SharePoint" he is shown a page where he sees ALL our SharePoint site's structure. He sees sites that he doesn't even have permission to see.

Is it possible to limit what the user sees at that page or remove the option altogether?

Comment: I've heard we can do things via CSS according to http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2012/08/sharepoint-ribbon-css-tips-tricks/